# Form validation not working for simple email field

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

Form validation is not working when i use to validate the email.

**Here is my code**

```
<form id="forgetForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<input placeholder="Email" class="text_box1" type="email" name="email" ng-model="forget.email" required="required">
<span class="errorMessage" ng-show="forgetForm.email.$error.email && !forgetForm.email.$pristine" class="help-inline">Email is not valid</span> 
<span class="errorMessage" ng-show="forgetForm.email.$error.required && !forgetForm.email.$pristine" class="help-inline">Email is required.</span>
<button style="width:auto" class="sign_up" ng-click="doForget(forget)" data-ng-disabled="forgetForm.$invalid" >Get a Password</button>
</form>
```

In the above code i write validation to check

1. Input should email
2. It is required.
3. Only if the form was without the button should be enabled.

But unfortunately both 3 were not working.

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could form validation of their fields using `formName.fieldName.$error`, Here you have missed to add `name` attribute on `form` & it should be `name="forgetForm"`

**Markup**

```
<form id="forgetForm" name="forgetForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   ..fields here..
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Can you help me solving this problem please ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31217856/4918996

Comment: @CableRaja check I gave answer there