# Angularjs not allowing square brackets in the url parameter - '['

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-http

I want to call and external api

It is working fine if i have parameters like this

```
$http.post('http://api.myprivatebox.com/users.json', { email : email, password : password}).then(function (results) 
 {
    console.log('mid');
 });
```

But when i use the parameter like `user[token]`

It is showing me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` Error

So, How can i send parameters with `[` square brackets

Like this

```
$http.post('http://api.myprivatebox.com/users.json', { email : email, password : password, user[token] : token}).then(function (results) 
 {
    console.log('mid');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the key by index notation of array as you want to set `user['token']` dynamically

**Code**

```
var formData = { email : email, password : password};

formData[user['token']] = token; //assuming user & token object has already defined

//user[token] : token

$http.post('http://api.myprivatebox.com/users.json', formData).then(function(results) {
    console.log('mid');
});
```

Comment: Getting `ReferenceError: user is not defined`

Comment: @CableRaja thats why I said you should have user value defined befor using there..

Comment: Shall i define like this ? `var user =""`

Comment: @CableRaja nope it should have var `user = {"token": 'something' }` coudl you explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @CableRaja do you have `token` value in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

`user[token]` is no a valid key. You have to wrap it in quotes!

Try `"user[token]"`